# Laravel split into 5

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

The problem is i splitted into 5 parts. how do i print them 5 `foreachs` by `$collection`. how do i take splitted`$collection`.

**ExamsController@create**

```
$groups = $questions->split(5);
$groups->toArray();
dd($groups);
```

**dd($groups)**

```
Collection {#455 ▼
  #items: array:5 [▼
    0 => Collection {#394 ▶}
    1 => Collection {#619 ▶}
    2 => Collection {#407 ▶}
    3 => Collection {#398 ▶}
    4 => Collection {#275 ▶}
  ]
}
```

**Create.blade.php**

```
@foreach($questions as $question)
 ......
@endforeach
```

**Update**

```
@foreach ($collections as $i => $collection)
@foreach ($collection as $a => $question)
    var_dump($question);
@endforeach</br>
@foreach ($collection as $b => $question)
    var_dump($question);
@endforeach</br>
@foreach ($collection as $c => $question)
    var_dump($question);
@endforeach</br>
@foreach ($collection as $d => $question)
    var_dump($question);
@endforeach</br>
@foreach ($collection as $e => $question)
    var_dump($question);
@endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: make another foreach inside foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are splitting your returned rows from your model into 5 collections. Each collection holds `x` amount of questions. You need to iterate over your collections as well as the questions within your collections.

Another `foreach` loop should do the trick.

```
$collections = $questions->split(5);
```

We could imagine that `$collections` would look something like this:

```
$collections = [   
    ['Q1?', 'Q2?'], // collection 1
    ['Q3?', 'Q4?'], // collection 2
    ['Q5?', 'Q6?'], // collection 3
    ['Q7?', 'Q8?'], // collection 4
    ['Q9?']         // collection 5
];
```

Iterating over that sort of structure would take 2 `foreach` loops as previously mentioned.

- First to iterate the collections
- And secondly to iterate through each question within the current collection being iterated through.

That looks like this:

```
foreach ($collections as $i => $collection) {
    foreach ($collection as $j => $question) {
        echo "Collection $i, Question $j : $question \n";
    }
}
```

**Update:**

The expected output can be found below:

(Notice how `$i` and `$j` are related to `$collection` and `$question` through each iteration)

Here is the PHP Sandbox code:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/77fb25e94a7ab81e699b99d5e354a1c5fe3a0d11

```
Collection 0, Question 0 : Q1? 

Collection 0, Question 1 : Q2? 

Collection 1, Question 0 : Q3? 

Collection 1, Question 1 : Q4? 

Collection 2, Question 0 : Q5? 

Collection 2, Question 1 : Q6? 

Collection 3, Question 0 : Q7? 

Collection 3, Question 1 : Q8? 

Collection 4, Question 0 : Q9?
```

Here Laravel's official documentation on this: 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-split

Comment: You only need 2 `foreach` loops. An outer loop & an inner loop. It looks like you are confused at the `$key => $value` syntax within a foreach loop. (I used `$i => $colllection` and `$j => $question`). Please see my updated answer that includes expected output and also my PHP sandbox link so you can see how everything works.